# Aggressivly Ram Caching with RAMdisk and readyboost

Tags: memory, performance, cache, ramdisk, readyboost

I am thinking about using a RAMdisk and Readyboost on Windows 10 to attempt to boost my read/write speed. I understand that windows will automatically cache recently used data in ram, but whenever I look at RAM usage in the performance monitor, a good chunk of the RAM is listed as being free instead of standby. Additionally, if it is caching recently used things, would it not be better to cache something that might be used soon (as readyboost does), vs something that was recently used?

I am looking for any possible flaws in my reasoning or logic here. Unlike people in plenty of my researches, I have not intention to place swap on the RAMdisk (that defeats the purpose of swap), just a readyboost cache.

Edit 1: my question here is is this a proper train of logic, or am I missing some details that would prove this is not the best route to take.

Comment: I see no question. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, I was not too clear, updated the question

Comment: Is your system disk an SSD? SuperFetch is disabled by default in that case. ReadyBoost is not an independent caching mechanism. RB simply allows Windows to use e.g. a USB thumb drive as additional space for SuperFetch. ReadyBoost will not use your RAMdisk, if that's what you were thinking. As for "better to cache things that are likely to be used soon", that's what SuperFetch does, but it does this by assuming that files recently used are likely to be used again soon; it doesn't have any other way to predict the future.  Just what operations do you think are limited by your disk speed?

Comment: It's a 5400rpm disk drive.

Comment: Get an M.2 SSD which is 4x faster than a regular ssd.  Do you need more speed than that?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a laptop. I wish the fix was that simple. I'm trying to find a way that does not cost me anything anyways.

Comment: No; As pointed out.  ReadyBoost isn't applicable to a RAMDisk unless you have less physical men then your system actually needs then ReadyBoost does nothing (and at a certain amount of physical memory ReadyBoost cannot even be enabled).  Superfetch should obviously be enabled if you have a mechanical drive.  Your not going to get the type of results from a RAMDisk like you think you will

Comment: @Ramhound Huh. In that case, I have a related question that I will be posting right now on superuser, more directly related to ram.

Comment: Though it did seem to help a bit when I tried it. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Also, on a similar note, why does readyboost help at all (and I have had it do so in the past), if the flash drive I am using has a slower read/write rate than the internal hard drive? Is it just because the hard drive has too many things running at once, so its read rate is maxed out, and the flash drive just offloads a bit?

Comment: @user173724 You don't mention how much memory you have, but ReadyBoost cannot be enabled, once you have a certain amount of memory installed.  ReadyBoost will not help your performance and it cannot be used with a RAMDrive.  Flash drive isn't going to have a slower write/read speed then a mechanical drive.

Comment: @Ramhound I was able to use readyboost on a ram drive. I have 8GB of ram. Also, crystaldiskmark shows that my internal drive has a 4x the read/write speed of a flash drive plugged into my USB port. (70MB/s vs 17MB/s)

Comment: If you have more than 8 GB ReadyBoost will provide no be benefit.  Windows will even tel you this on a ReadyBoost drive

Comment: Well I have 8, so that does not happen for me.

Comment: @Ramhound  >> Flash drive isn't going to have a slower write/read speed then a mechanical drive.>> Flash drives are 5-10x slower, particularly with writes. Internal I/O will always be faster than external.

Comment: @user173724  As above Ready Boost won't help, and Ram Disks are nothing but snake oil. If you want fast r/w you could get an SSD or M2, depending on laptop.  Consider that files are always cached into RAM, negating the benefit of an SSD. File caching works best when the machine isn't powered cycled constantly,( possibly why you don't have a lot in standby)..with laptops it's usually better to buy an SSD. So That's what I would recommend in your case. :)